# What are the freedom of breaking vectors into it's components?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, vectors

I came across some problems in which the way I broke vectors into it's components didn't gave me answer. Here are few of them:

[image]

Above mass $m$ is hanging with spring as shown, they broke $T$ in vertical and horizontal direction, for equilibrium sum of vertical components of $T$ should balanced $mg$.

Now consider the following:

Inextensible strings are pulled with velocity $u$, now here they consider $U$ as vectors and velocity on strings as it's components, no not like above in which $T$ was broken into vertical and horizontal.

[image]

What is the logic behind this, when to broke vectors into vertical and horizontal ($1st$ example) and when to do as done in $2nd$ example.

Comment: www.physicsclassrom.com and read up on vectors and free body diagrams, hyperphysics is also very good

Comment: Adding vectors before or after breaking them into components yields the same result. Either approach gives the correct answer.

Comment: Let's see what you did in the case where you weren't able to get the answer.

Comment: +1. Good question. I do not think this requires further explanation. You are clearly asking why you add the two forces $T$ using the parallelogram rule for vectors, but you cannot add the two velocities $u$ in the same way.